# Dynamic background image based on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack

In my style block I have code like this

```
<style lang="scss">
    .item {
        background: url('~@assets/images/i10.png');
    }
</style>
```

As per my specific needs I need to load the image from the javascript variable thats being injected in html page. e.g in index.html file coming up from server it could be

```
itemURL = '/abc/def/def/img.png';
```

Something like:

```
<style lang="scss">
    .item {
        background: url([window.itemURL);
    }
</style>
```

and then I need to use that url as background image of item.

I can't use document.getElementBy(xyz) as item is loading/unloading dynamically into DOM.

Note: Its vuejs project created via vue command line tools

Comment: are u writing .vue file, vue component? something like this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: its .vue file!!! yeah single file components

Answer (score 0):

u can use img tag instead of css style

```
<template>
  <div>
      <img
        :src="url"
      >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.url = injectImageUrl() // js function to inject url
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use props? But I don't think it's possible to access the props from inside the style tag. The only way to do this is by using inline styling.

```
<template>
  <div :style={ backgroundImage: 'url('+ imgUrl +')' }>
         
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      imgUrl: {
        type: String,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```